# C++ handling of numerical data types of different sizes

Tags: c++, bigint, data-representation

Suppose you have a data structure that stores natural numbers (though the challenge is the same for real numbers). You want the data structure to consume the minimal memory required, but you do want to support large numerical values. The ideal data structure would store in memory each value in an area fitting in size to the value.

My question: does C++ offer any tools to tackle this challenge? I can try and work-out a "C way" solution by allocating my own memory buffer and keeping pointers into the buffer from my data structure, but now I keep pointers instead of numbers, not much of an improvement, memory-size speaking.

I find it a challenging issue, due to the requirement in C++ to keep specific type to each identifier. I'll be grateful for your comments.

Comment: Any overhead to track the actual type along with a pointer offset is likely more than you'd pay to just use a large enough integral type (i.e., `unsigned long long`).

Comment: C++ does not include that as part of the standard C++ library.  You'll have to create your own, or use one of the many C++ *bigint* implementations or Boost [multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Do you need to store values larger than the capacity of a single machine word?

Comment: If you know the distribution of number sizes then one can devise a compression algorithm that efficiently stores a series of these numbers. Tradeoffs involved speed of reading back the numbers v minimal storage requirements.

Comment: A template would allow you to define what the types are and a function that deduces the types from the parameters (like std::make_pair) would make it fairly transparent.  But remember comparing the structs will then be harder because they won't be compatible types - you will have to do special memberwise comparison.

Comment: The other thing is that the last item in the struct can be an array without a length so that you can dynamically allocate a struct larger than that.  If you are clever with a union you could do small number optimization and still dynamically allocate enough for any size.

Answer (score 1):

> You want the data structure to consume the minimal memory required
> but you do want to support large numerical values. The ideal data structure would store in memory each value in an area fitting in size to the value.

The representation is more complicated than you think. Suppose the number I want to store is 2 to the power of 1014. I could store it using a 127-byte binary representation. But I could also decide on a different representation in which it takes less space, e.g. a variable-length representation in which I can store just the number 1014, and an indication there is only 1 bit up in a binary representation. Specifically, I could store an RLE-encoded binary representation.

In fact, one can show that the "ideal" representation, asymptotically, would be storing a representation of the shortest Turing machine which produces the desired number as an output. That is the number's [Kolmogorov/Solomonoff complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), and it is incomputable!

But let's bring the discussion back down to reality...

> My question: does C++ offer any tools to tackle this challenge?

Well, in both C and C++ you have language-level integral types of varying sizes, and the [`stdint.h`/`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) header which offers some integer types with specific sizes (`int8_t`, `int16_t` etc. and `uint8_t`, uint16_t` etc. - sizes are in bits).

> I can try and work-out a "C way" solution by allocating my own memory buffer and keeping pointers into the buffer from my data structure, but now I keep pointers instead of numbers, not much of an improvement, memory-size speaking.

If you want to be able to store arbitrarily large numbers, there is no escaping having to allocate memory dynamically - whether it's C or C++. The difference will be in how this allocation is made and how you manage and interact with your allocated-memory-based number representation data structure. Such a data structure is typically named a "big integer" or "bigint" for short. And libraries which offer these, and also supports arbitrary-precision fractional numbers, are often known as "multi-precision" libraries.

Naturally, there are some bigint and multi-precision number libraries you could check out. Perhaps the best known and one of the older ones is [Boost Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html). Some newer and relatively popular big-integer libraries are [faheel's BigInt](https://github.com/faheel/BigInt) and [Kaspars Klavin's bigint](https://github.com/kasparsklavins/bigint).

In C, it might be [GMP - The GNU Multiprecision library](https://gmplib.org/), which is also one of the "back-ends" for Boost Multiprecision.